# nodejs modify strings in mongodb

Tags: database, string, mongodb

I am trying to modify test: in my mongodb collection test.users with `

```
User({
    test: "testchange"
})
user.save().then(function () {
    console.log("user has been inserted")
}).catch(function () {
    console.log("Failed")
})
```

However it says user has been inserted but it never changes on the database. I have been trying four a couple hours now and really am just completely lost :( This is what the schema looks like

```
    var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    email: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    username: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        required: true,
        trim: true
    },
    test: {
        type: String,
        required: true,
    }
});
```

And then I get it with this

```
var testt = ('still same')
var userData = {
    username: req.body.username,
    test: testt
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. :)

Comment: Are you passing "_id" while Save() ?

Comment: no I do not think so honestly i am just trying to figure this out it is a whole new area for me o.o

Comment: something like req.session.userId = user._id; maybe?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.save/

Comment: this?        db.test.save(
        testt,
        {
          test: testt
        }
     )

Comment: it gives me this error :/ TypeError: Cannot read property 'save' of undefined

Comment: Use update (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) to update specific field by passing it's documented Id. Save is used for inserting document. (https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Save](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-save) is used to insert the document only. Use [update](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#document_Document-update) to change the specific field by some unique key. I have used `email` here.

Check below code sample:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
  Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true
  },
  username: {
      type: String,
      unique: true,
      required: true,
      trim: true
  },
  test: {
      type: String,
      required: true,
  }
});

var User = mongoose.model('UserTest', UserSchema);

function get(){
  var user = new User({
    username: "sd",
    email: "sss@gmail.com",
    test: "tes123"
  });
  user.save().then(function (data) {
    console.log("user has been inserted");
    console.log(data);
    update(); // Calling immediately to quick test only....
  }).catch(function (e) {
    console.log("Failed", e)
  });
}

function update(){
  User.update({email : "sss@gmail.com"}, { test: "testChanged" }, function (err, data) {
    console.log("user has been updated");
    console.log(data);
  });
}

get();
```

**Database Record:**

```
/* 1 */
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bd2db2ebe39c50d99037533"),
    "username" : "sd",
    "email" : "sss@gmail.com",
    "test" : "testChanged",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

**Console Output:**

```
user has been inserted
{ __v: 0,
  username: 'sd',
  email: 'sss@gmail.com',
  test: 'tes123',
  _id: 5bd2db2ebe39c50d99037533 }
user has been updated
{ ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 }
```

Comment: nice this also worked      `User.update({ test: 'Tobi' }, function (err, raw) {
      if (err) return handleError(err);
      console.log('The raw response from Mongo was ', raw);
    });` Thank you man for the help :)))))